# Does declaring a default ctor explicitly disallow the generation of synthesized ctors?

Tags: c++

One basic question that I'm wondering whether I get the correct answer is this:

Why case 1 doesn't work but case 2 work? (Assuming in main() we write `Boo<int> b;`

**Case 1**

```
template <typename T>
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo();
private:
};
```

**Case 2**

```
template <typename T>
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo() = default;
private:
};
```

I think the reason **Case 1** doesn't work is because the compiler sees that we declare a ctor so it ceases to generate synthesized ctors. When we declare a class object the compiler cannot find the definition of the required default ctor so this is a compilation error.

The reason **Case 2** works is because `= default` explicitly allows the compiler to generate a default ctor for us.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: [This copy-constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and [this movement-constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) might be helpful.

Comment: As for "case 1 doesn't work but case 2 work", can you please elaborate? First of all please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Then tell us what's wrong with the MVCE, *how* it "doesn't work". Very related: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the reason Case 1 doesn't work is because the compiler sees that we declare a ctor so it ceases to generate synthesized ctors.

Partially true. It does not generate the default constructor but it still generates the copy constructor.

> When we declare a class object the compiler cannot find the definition of the required default ctor so this is a compilation error.

That would be a linker error, not a compiler error.

You can resolve it easily be defining the constructor.

```
template <typename T>
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo() {}
private:
};
```

Comment: Thanks indeed it's a linker error. Can I add one question? Suppose after `private:` I have `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> data`, this will give me a runtime error. Is the reason similar to the first case? `Boo() = default;` also gives me the same error and I have to write `Boo() : data(std::make_shared<std::vector<T>>()) {}`

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey, you are on the right track. Yes, you need to initialize `data` like you have if you want to use it in a meaningful way.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey Even if you don't initialize `data` in the constructor, you shouldn't be getting a runtime error unless you are ACCESSING `data` before you have initialized it. For instance, using `shared_ptr::operator->` or `shared_ptr::get()` when `data` doesn't hold a pointer to a valid `vector<T>` object. Simply copying `data` in a user-defined or compiler-synthesized constructor is OK, so whatever runtime error you are getting is due to some other mistake you are doing.

Comment: @RSahu Sorry but one more question. For the previous comment (the one with shared pointer), why it is impossible for the compiler to generate synthesized default ctor? I read that only when the compiler cannot default initialize something then it will throw an error. I don't know why it cannot do so with pointer/smart pointer.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey what makes you think it can't?  `shared_ptr` is default-constructible, so the compiler most definitely CAN generate a default constructor if you LET IT do so.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are correct, I'm using push_back(), which make sense.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah I was not thinking correctly, sorry, the compilation is OK and the runtime error is caused by a push_back, don't know how I mixed them. Thumb up for clearing my mind! Actually when I look back, I should have known all of these.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are getting an undefined reference linker error in Case 1. The reason it "doesn't work" is simply because you have declared the constructor `Boo()` but not defined it. If in case 1 you had written `Boo() {}` (defined the constructor with an empty body), the linker would not complain.